# delete from S3 using api php using wildcard

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3

i have this working code to delete files and folders from s3.
how would you delete using wildcard * ?

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$bucket = 'mybucket';
$folder = 'myDirectory/*';// this doesnt work

$response = $s3->get_object_list($bucket, array(
   'prefix' => $folder
));

foreach ($response as $v) {
    $s3->delete_object($bucket, $v);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably *using wildcard ** means you want to delete all objects at once rather than one at a time?

This is possible via [delete_all_objects($bucket, $pcre)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/delete_all_objects), where `$pcre`is an optional *Perl-Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) to filter the names against* (default is `PCRE_ALL`, which is  `"/.*/i"`), e.g.:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$response = $s3->delete_all_objects($bucket, "#myDirectory/.*#");
```

I've chosen `#` rather than the usual `/` as the pattern enclosing delimiter to avoid escaping (not a problem with the single slash here, but it get's messy soon for more complex cases), see [Delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for details.

---

#### Implementation Note

Please note that deleting multiple objects had not been possible in the past at the Amazon S3 API level and simulated in the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) with a for loop within `delete_all_objects()` as well, i.e. it used one request per object still; fortunately, Amazon has finally introduced [Amazon S3 - Multi-Object Delete](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_can_I_delete_large_numbers_of_objects) in December 2011:

> [Amazon S3's](http://aws.amazon.com/s3) new Multi-Object Delete gives you the ability to
>   delete up to 1000 objects from an S3 bucket with a single request.

Support for *S3 Multi Object Delete* has been added to the *AWS SDK for PHP* shortly thereafter accordingly, see [AWS SDK for PHP 1.4.8 "Zanarkand"](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/2917833986024270):

> The AmazonS3 class now allows you to delete multiple Amazon S3 objects
>   using a single HTTP request. This has been exposed as the
>   delete_objects() method, and the delete_all_objects() and
>   delete_all_object_versions() methods have been rewritten to leverage this new Amazon S3 feature.

An example for a dedicated multi-object delete (i.e. without wildcards) is shown as well:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$response = $s3->delete_objects($bucket, array(
    'objects' => array(
        array('Key' => 'file1.txt'),
        array('Key' => 'file2.txt'),
    )
));
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to delete by prefix (as close to wildcard as I have gotten).

call like: `_delete_by_prefix_amazon('pdfs/1-')`

```
/**
 * Delete files by folder and prefix for Amazon 
 *
 * Deletes files from a service based on a prefix. 
 * For Amazon prefix must contain folder.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  prefix
 * @return  mixed   response from service api
 */
function _delete_by_prefix_amazon($prefix = ''){

    $s3 = new AmazonS3($credentials);

    $objects = $s3->get_object_list($bucket, array('prefix' => $prefix));


    $delete = array('objects'=>array());
    foreach ($objects as $object)
    {
        $delete['objects'][]['key'] = (string)$object;
    }
    //debug($delete);
    return $s3->delete_objects($this->bucket, $delete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [AWS SDK for PHP v2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/), you can do the following:

```
/**
 * Delete objects by prefix. 
 * 
 * @param string $bucketName The name of the bucket that you want to delete 
 * from (ex: "mybucket").
 * @param string $prefix A prefix to delete (ex: 'trash/').
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
function deleteByPrefix($bucketName, $prefix)
{   
    if(empty($prefix)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('prefix can\'t be empty');
    }

    //get all matching objects
    /* @var $iterator \Aws\S3\Iterator\ListObjectsIterator */
    $iterator = $this->s3Client->getListObjectsIterator(
                    array(
                        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
                        'Prefix' => $prefix,
                    )
                );

    //delete the matching objects
    $result = $this->s3Client->deleteObjects(
                                array(
                                    'Bucket'  => $bucketName,
                                    'Objects' => $iterator->toArray(),
                                )
                            );
}
```

Note that this will currently work for deleting up to 1000 objects at a time (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjectsUsingPHPSDK.html)).