# How to delete files recursively from an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have the following folder structure in S3. Is there a way to recursively remove all files under a certain folder (say `foo/bar1 or foo or foo/bar2/1` ..)

```
foo/bar1/1/..
foo/bar1/2/..
foo/bar1/3/..

foo/bar2/1/..
foo/bar2/2/..
foo/bar2/3/..
```

Answer (score 281):

With the latest [aws-cli python command line tools](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), to recursively delete all the files under a folder in a bucket is just:

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://your_bucket_name/foo/
```

Or delete everything under the bucket:

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://your_bucket_name
```

If what you want is to actually delete the bucket, there is one-step shortcut:

```
aws s3 rb --force s3://your_bucket_name
```

which will remove the contents in that bucket recursively then delete the bucket.

Note: the `s3://` protocol prefix is required for these commands to work

Comment: this should be the answer. It's a (new-ish) standard, powerful tool, designed for things just like this question

Comment: This is deleting the files just fine but its also deleting the bucket after deleting the files. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Naveen as I said above, `rm` will only delete files but `rb --force` will delete the files *and* the bucket.

Comment: @number5 I used the following -> aws s3 rm --recursive s3://your_bucket_name and this deletes the bucket as well. I even tried aws s3 rm --recursive s3://your_bucket_name --exclude "*" --include "*.gz" and this did not help either.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth updating the first example to show that you can specify a path? eg "aws s3 rm --recursive s3://your_bucket_name/foo/bar1"

Comment: hoping i can use this to change the permissions on a set of objects! about to find out.

Comment: using `--recursive` deletes the folder as well.

Comment: how do you delete all your buckets?

Comment: @RyanTuck do you know how to stop it from removing the folder?

Comment: @Moseleyi i believe that you can't actually have an empty folder in an s3 bucket

Comment: @schmijos You are right, it does not work for versioning. Further I did disable the versioning and tried the --force still no use. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @MarcellodeSales AWS S3 API (or aws cli) doesn't support that, it's on many people's wish list, so hopefully AWS will implement it someday

Comment: @number5 How come this solution has been tagged by 82 people? LOL

Comment: @MarcellodeSales at least 82 people found it useful with non-versioned S3 buckets?

Comment: Note that AWS Lambda does not have `aws`-cli preinstalled.

Comment: NOTICE: You have to use aws s3 rm --recursive s3://bucket/ --exclude="*" --include="/folder_path/*" As per aws s3 help manual --include and exclude usage. Notice there has to be a STAR after the folder path

Comment: just be careful, it's working...

Answer (score 65):

This used to require a dedicated API call per key (file), but has been greatly simplified due to the introduction of [Amazon S3 - Multi-Object Delete](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_can_I_delete_large_numbers_of_objects) in December 2011:

> [Amazon S3's](http://aws.amazon.com/s3) new Multi-Object Delete gives you the ability to
>   delete up to 1000 objects from an S3 bucket with a single request.

See my answer to the related question [delete from S3 using api php using wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9054601) for more on this and respective examples in PHP (the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) supports this since [version 1.4.8](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/2917833986024270)).

Most AWS client libraries have meanwhile introduced dedicated support for this functionality one way or another, e.g.:

#### Python

You can achieve this with the excellent [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) Python interface to AWS roughly as follows (untested, from the top of my head):

```py
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket("bucketname")
bucketListResultSet = bucket.list(prefix="foo/bar")
result = bucket.delete_keys([key.name for key in bucketListResultSet])
```

#### Ruby

This is available since [version 1.24](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/1484692008474752) of the [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) and the release notes provide an example  as well:

```rb
bucket = AWS::S3.new.buckets['mybucket']

# delete a list of objects by keys, objects are deleted in batches of 1k per
# request.  Accepts strings, AWS::S3::S3Object, AWS::S3::ObectVersion and 
# hashes with :key and :version_id
bucket.objects.delete('key1', 'key2', 'key3', ...)

# delete all of the objects in a bucket (optionally with a common prefix as shown)
bucket.objects.with_prefix('2009/').delete_all

# conditional delete, loads and deletes objects in batches of 1k, only
# deleting those that return true from the block
bucket.objects.delete_if{|object| object.key =~ /\.pdf$/ }

# empty the bucket and then delete the bucket, objects are deleted in batches of 1k
bucket.delete!
```

Or:

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.delete('your_bucket', :force => true)
```

Comment: should use the new `aws cli` like @number5 's answer below http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html

Answer (score 50):

You might also consider using Amazon S3 Lifecycle to create an expiration for files with the prefix `foo/bar1`.

Open the S3 browser console and click a bucket.  Then click Properties and then LifeCycle.

Create an expiration rule for all files with the prefix `foo/bar1` and set the date to 1 day since file was created.

Save and all matching files will be gone within 24 hours.

Just don't forget to remove the rule after you're done!

No API calls, no third party libraries, apps or scripts.

I just deleted several million files this way.

**A screenshot showing the Lifecycle Rule window (note in this shot the Prefix has been left blank, affecting all keys in the bucket):**

[image]

Comment: Great idea for using Lifecycle instead of some delete command.

Comment: Exactly, let S3 do it for you.

Comment: You can also apply this to the entire bucket, enabling you to delete the bucket.

Comment: I wonder if you could use "0" as the Time Period for days expiration, to queue it's immediate delete?

Answer (score 23):

The voted up answer is missing a step.

Per aws s3 help:

> Currently, there is no support for the use of UNIX style wildcards in a
>          command's  path  arguments.   However,  most  commands  have  `--exclude "<value>"` and `--include "<value>"`  parameters  that  can  achieve  the
>          desired  result......... When there are multiple
>          filters, the rule is the filters that appear later in the command  take
>          precedence  over filters that appear earlier in the command.  For example, if the filter parameters passed to the command were `--exclude "*"` `--include "*.txt"` All files will be excluded from the command  except  for  files  ending
>          with  .txt

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://bucket/ --exclude="*" --include="/folder_path/*"
```

Answer (score 12):

With `s3cmd` package installed on a Linux machine, you can do this

`s3cmd rm s3://foo/bar --recursive`

Comment: According to the help it is either single-object delete `s3cmd del s3://BUCKET/OBJECT` or whole bucket delete `s3cmd rb s3://BUCKET`. There is no `s3cmd rm`, at least according to `s3cmd --help`.

Comment: `s3cmd rm` is in the help as of 2019 (as an alias for del), this is an excellent answer. The `aws` cli tools only work against a `/` terminating prefix, but not a folder and partial filename prefix, whereas s3cmd works in both cases. This answer needs lots more upvotes, I had to scroll way too far to find the right solution.

Answer (score 9):

In case if you want to remove all objects with "foo/" prefix using Java AWS SDK 2.0

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.*;

//...

ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = ListObjectsRequest.builder()
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .prefix("foo/")
    .build()
;
ListObjectsResponse objectsResponse = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);

while (true) {
    ArrayList<ObjectIdentifier> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Iterator<?> iterator = objectsResponse.contents().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        S3Object s3Object = (S3Object)iterator.next();
        objects.add(
            ObjectIdentifier.builder()
                .key(s3Object.key())
                .build()
        );
    }

    s3Client.deleteObjects(
        DeleteObjectsRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .delete(
                Delete.builder()
                    .objects(objects)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
    );

    if (objectsResponse.isTruncated()) {
        objectsResponse = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        continue;
    }

    break;
};
```

Comment: I can't find a more telling demonstration of what people don't like about Java than this answer...

Comment: @Jivan Java is not the problem. It is the s3 client library.

Answer (score 4):

In case using AWS-SKD for ruby V2.

```
s3.list_objects(bucket: bucket_name, prefix: "foo/").contents.each do |obj|
  next if obj.key == "foo/" 
  resp = s3.delete_object({
    bucket: bucket_name,
    key: obj.key,
  })
end
```

attention please, all "foo/*" under bucket will delete.

Answer (score 4):

To delete all the versions of the objects under a specific folder:

Pass the path `/folder/subfolder/` to the Prefix -

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("my-bucket-name")
bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix="foo/bar1/1/").delete()
```

Answer (score 3):

I just removed all files from my bucket by using PowerShell:

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName YOUR_BUCKET | % { Remove-S3Object -BucketName YOUR_BUCKET -Key $_.Key -Force:$true }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, I was trying to do this exact thing and had put -Key "%_.Key" which doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just saw that Amazon added a "How to Empty a Bucket" option to the AWS console menu:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/DeletingaBucket.html

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use lifecycle rule to delete whole bucket contents. Programmatically you can use following code (PHP) to PUT lifecycle rule.

```
$expiration = array('Date' => date('U', strtotime('GMT midnight')));
$result = $s3->putBucketLifecycle(array(
            'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
            'Rules' => array(
                array(
                    'Expiration' => $expiration,
                    'ID' => 'rule-name',
                    'Prefix' => '',
                    'Status' => 'Enabled',
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

In above case all the objects will be deleted starting Date - "Today GMT midnight".

You can also specify Days as follows. But with Days it will wait for at least 24 hrs (1 day is minimum) to start deleting the bucket contents.

```
$expiration = array('Days' => 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the following...

```
def delete_bucket
  s3 = init_amazon_s3
  s3.buckets['BUCKET-NAME'].objects.each do |obj|
    obj.delete
  end
end

def init_amazon_s3
  config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")
  AWS.config(:access_key_id => config['access_key_id'],:secret_access_key => config['secret_access_key'])
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s3cmd del --recursive s3://your_bucket --force
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use aws javascript sdk v3, You can do it using following commands:

- ListObjectsV2Command
- DeleteObjectsCommand

Following is the javascript code that you can execute in NnodeJS runtime to remove all files of specific folder:

```
const { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command, DeleteObjectsCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

// specify your region 
const AWS_REGION = 'ap-south-1';

// init s3 client
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: AWS_REGION });

/**
 * S3 utility class
 */
class S3Utility {

  /**
   * private function to send delete request to s3
   * 
   * @param s3Bucket 
   * @param s3Objects 
   * 
   * @returns boolean
   */
  async #deleteObjectsRequest(s3Bucket, s3Objects) {
    try {
      const objects = [];
      s3Objects.forEach((object) => {
        if (object.Key) {
          objects.push({ Key: object.Key });
        }
      });

      const deleteResponse = await s3Client.send(new DeleteObjectsCommand({
        Bucket: s3Bucket,
        Delete: {
          Objects: objects
        }
      }));

      return deleteResponse['$metadata'];
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('S3Utility.#deleteObjectsRequest : error ', error);
      return false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete all folder and files of s3 folder specified by s3BucketName and s3Folder
   * 
   * @param s3BucketName S3 bucket name
   * @param s3Folder S3 folder path, e.g data/site/images
   * 
   * @returns boolean
   */
  async deleteS3Folder(s3BucketName, s3Folder) {
    try {
      const s3Response = await s3Client.send(new ListObjectsV2Command({ Bucket: s3BucketName, Prefix: s3Folder }));
      const objectExists = (s3Response['$metadata']['httpStatusCode'] === 200
        && s3Response.hasOwnProperty('Contents')
        && Array.isArray(s3Response.Contents)
        && s3Response.Contents.length > 0) ? true : false;

      if (objectExists) {
        await this.#deleteObjectsRequest(s3BucketName, s3Response.Contents);
        await this.deleteS3Folder(s3BucketName, s3Folder);
      }

      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('S3Utility.#deleteS3Folder : error ', error);
      return false;
    }

  }

}

// use our s3 utility class using async/await 
async () => {
  try {
      const s3Utility = new S3Utility();
      await s3Utility.deleteS3Folder('my-bucket-name', 'data/site/images');
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
}
```

More references:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listobjectsv2command.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/deleteobjectscommand.html

Comment: why do you need to call `await this.deletes3folder(...)` again recursively?