# Delete renamed files due to filerev from S3 bucket

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, amazon-s3, gruntjs

I'm using Jenkins to build my AngularJS website and deploy it on a S3 bucket, and I'm also using *[filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev)* task through [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com). I use [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin) to deploy from Jenkins to the bucket, but when a static resource is renamed via *filerev* **when building the website, it's not removed from the bucket**.

I don't want to use `Object Expiration` attribute of S3, I just want to remove out-of-date resources after deployment. Thanks!

Comment: which version of angularjs ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the possibility to test this, but I would suggest you to try to delete the files from your S3 bucket by adding an [Execute shell](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=execute+shell+jenkins+script) step and use the AWS command line.
You can find how to do it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054985/how-to-delete-files-recursively-from-an-s3-bucket) or in the official [Amazon Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html).
After deleting everything, you can deploy the new version of your app with the Jenkins plugin.