# Delete objects in s3 using wildcard matching

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following working code to delete an object from Amazon s3

```
params := &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("Bucketname"),
        Key : aws.String("ObjectKey"),
    }
s3Conn.DeleteObjects(params)
```

But what i want to do is to delete all files under a folder using wildcard **. I know amazon s3 doesn't treat "x/y/file.jpg" as a folder y inside x but what i want to achieve is by mentioning "x/y*" delete all the subsequent objects having the same prefix. Tried [amazon multi object delete](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_can_I_delete_large_numbers_of_objects)

```
params := &s3.DeleteObjectsInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("BucketName"),
        Delete: &s3.Delete{
            Objects: []*s3.ObjectIdentifier {
                {
                    Key : aws.String("x/y/.*"), 
                },
            },
        },
    }
    result , err := s3Conn.DeleteObjects(params)
```

I know in php it can be done easily by *s3->delete_all_objects* as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054287/delete-from-s3-using-api-php-using-wildcard). Is the same action possible in GOlang.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the goamz package doesn't have a method similar to the PHP library's `delete_all_objects`.

However, the source code for the PHP `delete_all_objects` is available here (toggle source view): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/delete_all_objects

Here are the important lines of code:

```
public function delete_all_objects($bucket, $pcre = self::PCRE_ALL)
{
// Collect all matches
    $list = $this->get_object_list($bucket, array('pcre' => $pcre));

    // As long as we have at least one match...
    if (count($list) > 0)
    {
        $objects = array();

        foreach ($list as $object)
        {
            $objects[] = array('key' => $object);
        }

        $batch = new CFBatchRequest();
        $batch->use_credentials($this->credentials);

        foreach (array_chunk($objects, 1000) as $object_set)
        {
            $this->batch($batch)->delete_objects($bucket, array(
                'objects' => $object_set
            ));
        }

        $responses = $this->batch($batch)->send();
```

As you can see, the PHP code will actually make an HTTP request on the bucket to first get all files matching `PCRE_ALL`, which is defined [elsewhere](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/blob/master/services/s3.class.php#L352) as `const PCRE_ALL = '/.*/i';`.

You can only delete 1000 files at once, so `delete_all_objects` then creates a batch function to delete 1000 files at a time.

You have to create the same functionality in your go program as the goamz package doesn't support this yet. Luckily it should only be a few lines of code, and you have a guide from the PHP library.

It might be worth submitting a pull request for the goamz package once you're done!

Comment: Thank you have raised a pull with aws-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Using the [mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) tool you can do:

`mc rm -r --force https://BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/x/y`

it will delete all the objects with the prefix "x/y"

You can achieve the same with Go using [minio-go](https://github.com/minio/minio-go) like this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/minio/minio-go"
)

func main() {
    config := minio.Config{
        AccessKeyID:     "YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE",
        SecretAccessKey: "YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE",
        Endpoint:        "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
    }
    // find Your S3 endpoint here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

    s3Client, err := minio.New(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    isRecursive := true
    for object := range s3Client.ListObjects("BucketName", "x/y", isRecursive) {
        if object.Err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(object.Err)
        }
        err := s3Client.RemoveObject("BucketName", object.Key)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
            continue
        }
        log.Println("Removed : " + object.Key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, the AWS GoLang lib for S3 has received some new methods in S3 Manager to handle this task (in response to @Itachi's pr).

See Github record: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/448#issuecomment-309078450

Here is their example in v1: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/s3/DeleteObjects/DeleteObjects.go#L36

To get "wildcard matching" on paths inside the bucket, add the Prefix param to the [example's](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/s3/DeleteObjects/DeleteObjects.go#L36) ListObjectsInput call, as shown here:

```
    iter := s3manager.NewDeleteListIterator(svc, &s3.ListObjectsInput{
        Bucket: bucket,
        Prefix: aws.String("somePathString"),
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the game, but since I was having the same problem, I created a small pkg that you can copy to your code base and import as needed.

```
func ListKeysInPrefix(s s3iface.S3API, bucket, prefix string) ([]string, error) {
    res, err := s.Client.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Prefix: aws.String(prefix),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return []string{}, err
    }

    var keys []string
    for _, key := range res.Contents {
        keys = append(keys, *key.Key)
    }
    return keys, nil
}

func createDeleteObjectsInput(keys []string) *s3.Delete {
    rm := []*s3.ObjectIdentifier{}
    for _, key := range keys {
        rm = append(rm, &s3.ObjectIdentifier{Key: aws.String(key)})
    }
    return &s3.Delete{Objects: rm, Quiet: aws.Bool(false)}
}

func DeletePrefix(s s3iface.S3API, bucket, prefix string) error {
    keys, err := s.ListKeysInPrefix(bucket, prefix)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = s.Client.DeleteObjects(&s3.DeleteObjectsInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Delete: s.createDeleteObjectsInput(keys),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

So, in the case you have a bucket called "somebucket" with the following structure: `s3://somebucket/foo/some-prefixed-folder/bar/test.txt` and wanted to delete from `some-prefixed-folder` onwards, usage would be:

```
func main() {
    // create your s3 client here
    // client := ....
    err := DeletePrefix(client, "somebucket", "some-prefixed-folder")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This implementation only allows to delete a maximum of 1000 entries from the given prefix due `ListObjectsV2` implementation - but it is paginated, so it's a matter of adding the functionality to keep refreshing results until results are < 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete objects in S3 bucket using wildcard from CLI

```
aws s3 rm s3://<xyz bucket name>/2023/ --recursive --exclude '*' --include 'A*.csv'
```